# Akka: Actors sharing BalancingDispatcher stop getting ReceiveTimeouts

Tags: akka

We found a problem where a group of Actors that share a BalancingDispatcher stop getting ReceiveTimeout messages if they are not getting other messages.  At first, every actor in the group receives the ReceiveTimeout as expected, but rather quickly the number of Actors getting them drops off until only a single actor gets it.

If other messages are coming in it seems to prevent this from happening. It's only when the Actors cycle for a while getting nothing besides the ReceiveTimeout.

Here's an example:

```
// Akka version 2.1.1, Scala version 2.10.0

import akka.actor._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.collection.mutable

case class TimeoutReceived(actor: String, timestamp: Long)

class TimeoutPool(system: ActorSystem) {
  val timeouts = new mutable.MutableList[TimeoutReceived]

  class TimeoutActor extends Actor {
    override def preStart() = {
      super.preStart()
      context.setReceiveTimeout(100 milliseconds)
    }
    def receive = {
      case ReceiveTimeout =>
        println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " ReceiveTimeout " + self.path)
        timeouts += TimeoutReceived(self.path.name, System.currentTimeMillis())
    }
  }

  val actors: Iterable[ActorRef] =
    for (x <- (0 to 9).toList) yield {
      system.actorOf(Props(() => new TimeoutActor, "dispatcher"),
                     "example.actor" + x)
    }
}
```

So, you can just start one up with a config like `"dispatcher.type = BalancingDispatcher"` and watch the println output.  Before too long only one of the Actors will emit the "ReceiveTimeout" output.

Here's a test class that demonstrates the problem, and also shows that the Actors have not been shut down:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import org.scalatest.FunSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers

class ExampleSpec extends FunSpec with ShouldMatchers {
  describe("Balancing dispatcher example") {
    it("actors sharing dispatcher stop getting ReceiveTimeouts (except for one)") {
      val system = ActorSystem("TimeoutExample", ConfigFactory.parseString("dispatcher.type = BalancingDispatcher"))
      val pool = new TimeoutPool(system)
      // spin until we've accumulated 50 timeouts
      while(pool.timeouts.length < (50)) { Thread.sleep(500) }
      // grab the last cycle of ten that we recorded
      val lastTenTimeouts = pool.timeouts.toList.drop(40).take(10).map(_.actor.takeRight(1))

      // have the actors shut down?  No:
      pool.actors.forall(_.isTerminated == false) should be (true) // will pass

      // did each of the 10 actors get a timeout in the last cycle?
      lastTenTimeouts.distinct should have size(10) // will fail with size 1 or 2.

      system.shutdown()
    }
  }
}
```

Change that "BalancingDispatcher" to "Dispatcher" and the test will pass.

Is this a bug in Akka, or is it just not valid to use ReceiveTimeouts with a BalancingDispatcher for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Akka all actors that share a single BalancingDispatcher will also share a single mailbox, this can lead to the situation you've described above.

As stated in [ScalaDoc for the BalancingDispatcher](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/snapshot/index.html#akka.dispatch.BalancingDispatcher):

> An executor based event driven dispatcher which will try to redistribute work from busy actors to idle actors. It is assumed that all actors using the same instance of this dispatcher can process all messages that have been sent to one of the actors. I.e. the actors belong to a pool of actors, and to the client there is no guarantee about which actor instance actually processes a given message.
>
> Although the technique used in this implementation is commonly known as "work stealing", the actual implementation is probably best described as "work donating" because the actor of which work is being stolen takes the initiative.

Comment: Also, use of BalancingDispatcher (apart from really special cases) is discouraged in favor of routers, or even better, custom work distribution using plain actors.

Comment: Sergiy, thanks for the response.  We'd read that of course, and in our use case it is true that "all actors using the same instance of this dispatcher can process all messages that have been sent to one of the actors"... but the part about "there is no guarantee about which actor instance actually processes a given message" trips us up. What's annoying about this scenario is that it does distribute the messages for the first few cycles, fooling us into thinking it works, but as you point out, it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Endre - thanks for the note, in fact our fix to our code is to swap in a SmallestMailboxRouter for the BalancingDispatcher.